# Unable to mock interface with generic return type in Jmockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, jmockit

I am trying to write a Junit unit test which mocks an interface that extends the spring-data-jpa interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>. This interface provides the method

```
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

When I call this in my Expectations it wrongly records the return type as the type of the mocked interface rather than S (as resolved by my mocked interface) which causes a class cast exception.

I have debugged through and the generic signature it records is

```
<S:TT;>(TS;)TT;
```

There is a lot of code around figuring out what the return type is but eventually it comes up with the wrong answer. I'm fairly sure this is a bug but I hope someone can confirm this or tell me where I'm going wrong. One other thing to note is I am able to successfully mock other calls on the interface that just return T.

- Jmockit: 1.16
- JUnit: 4.12
- spring-data-jpa: 1.7.1.RELEASE

**Update with example**

I have put together a scaled down test case that demonstrates the issue (below). In doing so I have uncovered a strange quirk. In the test I have two MyEntity objects which I use in the two expectations. If I change the save expectation to take and return the same objecct as the findOne call, the bug does not occur.

**MyEntity.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class MyEntity
{
}
```

**MyRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long>
{

}
```

**DataAccess.java**

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private final MyRepository repository;

    public DataAccess(MyRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public MyEntity resaveEntity(long id)
    {
        MyEntity entity = repository.findOne(id);
        return repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

**DataAccessTest.java**

```
import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Mocked;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DataAccessTest
{

    @Test
    public void testResaveEntity(@Mocked final MyRepository repository) throws Exception
    {
        final MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        final MyEntity myEntity2 = new MyEntity();
        new Expectations()
        {
            {
                repository.findOne(1L);
                result = myEntity;

                repository.save(myEntity2);
                result = myEntity2;
            }
        };

        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(repository);
        dataAccess.resaveEntity(1);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Impl_MyRepository cannot be cast to MyEntity
at DataAccess.resaveEntity(DataAccess.java:16)
at DataAccessTest.testResaveEntity(DataAccessTest.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: can you post some code on the test that fails?

Comment: could you provide the test class and the repository class code?

Comment: As others already commented, you will need to show an example test, otherwise we can't do much to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the test. Where it reads

```
repository.save(myEntity2);
```

it should be

```
repository.save(myEntity1);
```

With this fix, the test should pass. On the other hand, that `ClassCastException` occurs because of a bug in JMockit, for which an [issue](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/158) was opened.

Comment: It's not really an error in the test. If there was some logic in resaveEntity() that made changes to myEntity before saving then you need to use myEntity2 to represent the updated object being passed to save(). I admit in this simple case it's not really needed but using the two different objects is what triggers the issue.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a link to the issue in the GitHub project.